# Create JSON file from a query with FOR JSON clause result in ADF

Tags: json, sql-server, azure, azure-data-factory

I need to create a JSON file from azure SQL database and store the file in Azure blob storage.
In ADF, I created a simple pipeline with one Copy Data activity to achieve this.
I used t-sql query with FOR JSON clause to get data from the database.

```
SELECT * FROM stage.Employee FOR JSON AUTO, ROOT ('main_root')
```

Here is my source:
[image]

And this is a sink:
[image]

After execute pipeline, the created file looks like this
[image]

I want to get a normal JSON file with the structure

```
{
"main_root": [
    {
        "Employee_No": "1000",
        "Status": "Employee",
        "..." "...",
        "..."
    },
    {
        "Employee_No": "1000",
        "Status": "Employee",
        "..." "...",
        "..."
    },
    {
        "Employee_No": "1000",
        "Status": "Employee",
        "..." 
      "...",
        "..."
```

Any help I will appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are building a hierarchical structure from a relation source, so you'll want to build your R2H logic in data flows to accommodate this data transformation.

Set the SQL DB table as your source and then build your hierarchical structure in a Derived Column with sub-columns for hierarchies and collect data into arrays using Aggregate with the collect() function.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That was all I need.

Comment: Can this be done in a way that infers the schema from the incoming data, rather than manually building it via Derived Columns?

Comment: Mark, multiple rows really isn't an acceptable output. If you are returning a JSON object, it should be one object. This is an issue in .net and also in ADF and has truncation in SSMS. Azure Data Studio returns the entire output. I have a complex JSON return object and it should output as one object. In .net, we have to loop rows and concatenate to return a string an entire object and now I'm running into multiple rows in ADF which is causing truncate in our output files.